# Is there bundle for textmate or sublime text 2 that will show me what value a ruby method returns?

Tags: ruby, textmatebundles, sublimetext

Is there bundle for textmate or sublime text 2 that will show me what value a ruby method returns?.

I'm looking for something with a tooltip that I can hover over a statement and have it  tell me what the method returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. For a method to return a value, you need to execute that method, passing in any appropriate parameters and operating on the current state of the object instance. Further, the value of a method may change depending on object state and parameters. How would the text editor have any idea what these would be?

The only time that "return value for a method" makes sense is during debugging, when you have stopped execution and are evaluating a particular method invocation. Neither TextMate nor Sublime Text are IDEs, and thus do not provide line-based debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you're looking for: [sublime-text-2-ruby-markers](https://github.com/mmims/sublime-text-2-ruby-markers)

To install:

From Sublime Text 2:
Tools > Command Palette
Find and Install "Ruby Markers"

Now when you type a line of code, append the line with " # =>" and hit Shift+Alt+U to see the return value of that line. You can also just add " #" followed by tab to save a few keystrokes (on a mac at least)

By default, any output from your program will also print as a comment to the bottom of your file, so to disable that:
Menu > Preferences > Package Settings > Ruby Markers > Settings - User
And paste this:

`{
  "strip_stdout": true,
  "xmpfilter_quiet": true
}`

Wow this is an old question :)